# Coldfusion 7, cookies not working with DNS name, but work with IP address

Tags: cookies, coldfusion, dns, ip

Running CF 7 on Windows 2003 Server with IIS 6.  Server is named usileng01.xyz.com.  It has one IP address 135.5.17.25 and three web sites defined in IIS.  All three are using the server's IP address on port 80.

1) Default Web Site - Home directory in IIS points to C:\Inetpub\wwwroot

2) itrac.web.xyz.com - has "Host header value" in IIS set to itrac.web.xyz.com.  Home directory points to E:\iTracDocumentRoot.  itrac.web.xyz.com is a DNS alias to usileng01.xyz.com.

3) itdata.web.xyz.com - has "Host header value" in IIS set to itdata.web.xyz.com.  Home directory points to E:\iTracDocumentRoot\IT. itdata.web.xyz.com is a DNS alias to usileng01.xyz.com

All three sites have anonymous access disabled and "Authenticated access" in IIS set to "Integrated Windows authentication" since PCs are logged into the AD domain.

When accessing the web server via a DNS name (either usileng01.xyz.com, itrac.web.xyz.com, or itdata.web.xyz.com), the CFID and JSESSIONID change on every access, so I'm unable to see the cookies.  I can set cookies fine and they appear in the PC's cookie file.

However, when accessing the web site via the server's IP address (e.g., http://135.5.17.25) the CFID and JSESSIONID remain the same and I can see the cookies.

I have tried all combinations of CFAPPLICATION's options sessionManagement, setDomainCookies, clientManagement, setClientCookies, and clientStorage.  Other than changing what's in the cookies, session, and client variables, nothing has worked.

Any idea why I can access cookies when using IP address but not DNS name?  And how to get them working with DNS names?

Comment: To be clear - when you hit itrac.web.xyz.com once you get a JsessionID, then when you refresh the page - hitting the exact same site hosted on the exact same server and same instance you get a different jsessionid - is that what you are saying?

Comment: Yes, a different jsessionid, CFID, and CFTOKEN every time I refresh the page when using DNS name.  Those variable stay the same when using IP address.

Comment: 2 things come to mind. First how is your application being named - what's the "name" in the Application.cfc or the cfapplication tag? Second, are you using any CFLOCATION tags within the code?

Comment: Worth trying opening up a private browser session and testing that the same thing happens.

Comment: The application names in CFAPPLICATION are "iTRAC", "IT", and "ECC_test".  The first two have CFLOCATION tags and the 3rd one doesn't (it's a small test page).  A couple additional points of info: this happens with IE 8, IE11, and Firefox.  I created a short test.asp script and everything was ok.